# MYSQLi prepared insert not working..

Tags: php, mysqli, prepare

I am stuck on mysqli prepare.. and I am all but certain there isn't a mistake in the prepared statement. Yet im getting the "call to non-member object error".. from what I recall this error only occurs if infact there is an error with the statement.." Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object ".. I'm not too sure if I have used any reserved words.. Maybe someone can help..

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO customers (cid, company, fname, sname, email,  mobile, email_notif, sms_notif, telephone, address, postcode, city, town, allowedLogin, date, addedby)
                          VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssssss", $id, $company, $fname, $sname, $email, $mobile, $emailnotif, $smsnotif, $telephone, $address, $postcode, $city, $town, $allowedLogin, $date, $addedby);

    if( $stmt->execute() )
    {   
        /* Free Result Set */
        $stmt->close();
        return true;    
    } 
   else
   {
        return "<p>".$mysqli->error."</p>";
   }
```

p.s I am passing the variables via a function call:

```
addCustomer($company,$fname,$sname,$email,$mobile,$smsnotif,$emailnotif,$telephone,$address,$postcode,$city,$town,$allowedLogin, $date, $addedby);
```

Comment: It's doing that because it's failing to prepare.  Use `$stmt->error` after you bind to find out why it's causing that error when you prepare it. Also, [according to documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html), `date` is a reserved word but doesn't need to be ticked out, however, I would try that as one of the first steps of troubleshooting.  Also, depending on the DB structure, if `cid` is `auto_increment`, that may cause the error as well, so try omitting it if it is.

Comment: a tip: for dealing with huuuuuge datasets, try PDO. passing arrays into this (and using named params when you want to) is a huge benefit.

Comment: Check for errors after each call. One of the earlier calls is failing, and the error message should help.'

Answer (score 1):

`date` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Try adding backticks around it.

Comment: This may have been true in MySQL < v5.0, but according to the >=v5.0 docs - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html `MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them.` and `DATE` is one of the ones listed.

Answer (score 0):

i see `$id` being in `bind_param` used but not passed from the function `addCustomer`

Comment: Wouldn't make a difference if it's failing to prepare.